# Intellij keeps freezing after Ubuntu update

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

Yesterday my IDE was working just fine until I updated my Ubuntu, where once I restarted my computer I noticed that every 3 seconds the application would freeze, even when I am only scrolling.

I have tried update my IDE to version 2019.3.4 but that did not do anything. I have also restarted my computer multiple times (futile attempt) and nothing changed.

It is only my IDE that is having issues, nothing else.

If it matter, this is the last few logs I see in my /var/log/apt/history-log:

```
Start-Date: 2020-04-15  08:25:05
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: thunderbird-locale-en-us:amd64 (1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, 1:68.7.0+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1)
End-Date: 2020-04-15  08:25:06

Start-Date: 2020-04-17  08:53:42
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: git-man:amd64 (1:2.20.1-2ubuntu1.19.10.1, 1:2.20.1-2ubuntu1.19.10.2)
End-Date: 2020-04-17  08:53:52

Start-Date: 2020-04-17  08:53:57
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: git:amd64 (1:2.20.1-2ubuntu1.19.10.1, 1:2.20.1-2ubuntu1.19.10.2)
End-Date: 2020-04-17  08:53:58

Start-Date: 2020-04-17  08:59:05
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.4811'
Upgrade: libasound2-data:amd64 (1.1.9-0ubuntu1.2, 1.1.9-0ubuntu1.3), slack-desktop:amd64 (4.4.0, 4.4.2), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (81.0.4044.92-1, 81.0.4044.113-1), google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java:amd64 (288.0.0-0, 289.0.0-0), google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python:amd64 (288.0.0-0, 289.0.0-0), google-cloud-sdk:amd64 (288.0.0-0, 289.0.0-0), libasound2:amd64 (1.1.9-0ubuntu1.2, 1.1.9-0ubuntu1.3)
End-Date: 2020-04-17  09:00:55
```

Intelij logs

```
2020-04-17 16:23:42,923 [ 663238]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Flushing logs. 
2020-04-17 16:23:42,924 [ 663239]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Scheduling next log flush in 60000 ms. 
2020-04-17 16:24:42,924 [ 723239]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Flushing logs. 
2020-04-17 16:24:42,925 [ 723240]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Scheduling next log flush in 60000 ms. 
2020-04-17 16:25:42,925 [ 783240]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Flushing logs. 
2020-04-17 16:25:42,925 [ 783240]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Scheduling next log flush in 60000 ms. 
2020-04-17 18:14:01,951 [7282266]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Flushing logs. 
2020-04-17 18:14:01,951 [7282266]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Scheduling next log flush in 60000 ms. 
2020-04-17 18:14:29,078 [7309393]   WARN - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - UI freezed for 6281ms, details saved to /home/user/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/system/log/threadDumps-freeze-20200417-181422-IU-193.6911.18-XRBackendNative.renderRectangle-6sec 
2020-04-17 18:14:45,107 [7325422]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Nautilus-Share-Message: 18:14:35.471: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)

Timed out 
2020-04-17 18:15:01,951 [7342266]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Flushing logs. 
2020-04-17 18:15:01,952 [7342267]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Scheduling next log flush in 60000 ms. 
2020-04-17 18:15:29,790 [7370105]   WARN - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - UI freezed for 7141ms, details saved to /home/user/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/system/log/threadDumps-freeze-20200417-181522-IU-193.6911.18-XRBackendNative.XRenderCompositeTextNative-7sec 
2020-04-17 18:15:37,807 [7378122]   WARN - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - UI freezed for 6956ms, details saved to /home/user/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/system/log/threadDumps-freeze-20200417-181530-IU-193.6911.18-XRBackendNative.XRenderRectanglesNative-6sec 
2020-04-17 18:15:37,925 [7378240]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - [project] git /usr/bin/git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false fetch origin --recurse-submodules=no --progress --prune 
2020-04-17 18:15:39,898 [7380213]   WARN - x.cache.CachedStatusCalculator - Hash mismatch between count and status: RevListCount[value=0,status=SUCCESS,top=<null>] ahead, RevListCount[value=0,status=SUCCESS,top=<null>] behind, status=SUCCESS <> RepoStatus[localHash=36e5a6a079c036e0f754108885825fd4b5226a05,localBranch=refs/heads/601-add-tracking-for-matches,remote=RepoStatusRemote[remoteTrackingBranch=refs/remotes/origin/601-add-tracking-for-matches,parentBranch=refs/remotes/origin/601-add-tracking-for-matches,parentHash=36e5a6a079c036e0f754108885825fd4b5226a05]] 
2020-04-17 18:15:47,800 [7388115]   WARN - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - UI freezed for 8042ms, details saved to /home/user/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/system/log/threadDumps-freeze-20200417-181539-IU-193.6911.18-XRBackendNative.XRenderRectanglesNative-8sec 
2020-04-17 18:16:02,670 [7402985]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Flushing logs. 
2020-04-17 18:16:02,671 [7402986]   INFO - .clearcut.ClearcutLogScheduler - Scheduling next log flush in 60000 ms.
```

I am assuming one of these updates messed up my system, but I am not sure which one(s) nor how to fix it properly.

Comment: What do the Intellij logs say?

Comment: @MattSchuchard ive updated the ticket with some the last logs

Comment: Looks like a known issue caused by kernel update: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2269

Comment: @y.bedrov Ah, you're right, thanks! Downgrading the kernel version, for now, is a work around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a known issue with the kernel version 5.3.0-46 and downgrading to 5.3.0-45 resolves the issue, by following the steps here: https://ixnfo.com/en/how-to-roll-back-kernel-ubuntu.html

Comment: You can also explicitly set the version you want by modifying the DEFAULT_GRUB in /etc/default/grub to something like this: GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-45-generic" and  then reboot your system.